# C++ "undefine" module keyword in include

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20, c++-modules, msvc14

I'd like to use C++20 modules in visual studio, but one of my projects uses [Magick++](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/d40010ee3c4eb3909adbb88c1e4f82588df76d5a/MagickCore/magick.h#L61-L97) which defines a `struct` with a member `char*` named "module" in "magick++.h":

> ```
> typedef struct _MagickInfo
> {
>   char
>     *name,
>     *description,
>     *version,
>     *mime_type,
>     *note,
>     *module; /* offending member here */
>
>   /* ... other members ... */
> } MagickInfo;
> ```

Can I tell the compiler to not process "module" in that specific #include?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`module` isn't a keyword (you can find the list of keywords in [[lex.key]](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.key) and verify that it isn't there).

Instead, it's an "identifier with special meaning" ([[lex.name]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex#name-2)), more commonly referred to as a *context-sensitive keyword*.

That is, there are only certain places where the `module` "keyword" is intended to be used, since module declarations can't appear everywhere. It's only those specific places that are going to be treated as module declarations. For a more thorough treatment of how the compiler might do this disambiguation, see [P0924](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0924r1.pdf).

One of the motivations for making `module` (and `import`) context-sensitive is that `module` is actually a fairly commonly used identifier in code - it's not just Magick++, there's also [Vulkan](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0795r0.pdf).

---

In short, the fact that you have a type with a member named `module` isn't going to cause problems. Having a *type* named `module` is worse (worse still if you have a global variable of that type - that could cause problems, but it would at least be possible to rewrite your code in such a way as to disambiguate the use of `module` in those situations).

Comment: Note that the OP might be using an older version of a compiler where `module` was a keyword.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think that is indeed the case.